# Can I save data/value in browser session storage using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

However, i can save and retrieve data to browser from clientside. I'm not sure, but is there any way I could do it from serverside. Thanks in advance for any solution and advices.

Comment: Why won't you try something and check ?

Comment: I looked an example at: http://code.runnable.com/Uhxav7qocnlxAAA8/asp-net-how-to-use-session but, this could not help me.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the solution. Below is the code I found, which helped me to expose data from server-side to the client side.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "",  "sessionStorage.setItem('Username','Something')", true);
```

Comment: I stuck again !!! .... How do I retrieve the client stored data again to backend???

Answer (score 1):

**For Creating `Session`**

```
Session["Username"] = " Mairaj";
```

**To Get Value from `Session`**

```
string userName = string.Empty;
if(Session["Username"] != null)
 userName= Session["Username"].ToString();
```

**To get value from `Session` in aspx page.**

```
var userName = '<% =Session["userName"]%>';
```

You can get value from `Session` in `aspx` page not in `external JS` file.

Comment: Ok that's what I tried, but how i could i retreive it from client side(js)